# ASP.Net in Mono on Linux "System.TypeLoadException" when starting

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, mono

I coded an ASP.net website in C# in Visual Studio on Windows to execute some Linux commands which should be run on a Raspberry Pi. I first had some problems with Monodevelop and some dll's which I then copied from Windows and it worked.

Now the debugger isn't having any problems but when it should load the page this error comes up:

```
System.TypeLoadException
    Could not resolve type with token 01000017

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
Details: Non-web exception.
Exception stack trace:
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00038] in <f712f98eb8e445c8918edaf595bbe465>:0
```

Do you guys know any help for me?

Comment: what version of mono are you using?

Comment: mono is on version 4.8.0 and monodevelop is on 5.10